# How to code a function that randomly selects a quote from an array? - Android Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

I am following an android coding tutorial and am try to make the quote selection random. Below is the unaltered code.

```
       final ArrayList<Quote> quoteList = new ArrayList<Quote>();

    Quote quote1 = new Quote("Would I rather be feared or loved? Easy. Both. I want people to fear how much they love me.", "Michael Scott");
    quoteList.add(quote1);

    Quote quote2 = new Quote("I'm not superstitious. But I am a little stitious.", "Michael Scott");
    quoteList.add(quote2);

    Quote quote3 = new Quote("I like waking up to the smell of bacon.", "Michael Scott");
    quoteList.add(quote3);

    Quote quote4 = new Quote("Wikipedia is the best thing ever. Anyone in the world can write anything they want about any subject. So you know you are getting the best possible information.", "Michael Scott");
    quoteList.add(quote4);

    Quote quote5 = new Quote("Mo' money, mo' problems.", "Michael Scott");
    quoteList.add(quote5);

    Quote quote6 = new Quote("SWAG! Stuff We All Get.", "Michael Scott");
    quoteList.add(quote6);

    Quote quote7 = new Quote("You just gots to get your freak on.", "Michael Scott");
    quoteList.add(quote7);

    Quote quote8 = new Quote("We're all homos. Homo sapiens.", "Michael Scott");
    quoteList.add(quote8);

    Quote quote9 = new Quote("Hate to see you leave but love to watch you go. 'Cause of your butt.", "Michael Scott");
    quoteList.add(quote9);

    Quote quote10 = new Quote("If a baby were president, there would be no taxes, there would be no war.", "Michael Scott");
    quoteList.add(quote10);
    //Add more quotes here


    touch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (count < quoteList.size()) {
                Quote q = quoteList.get(count);
                quoteText.setText(q.getQuote());
                personText.setText(q.getPerson());
                count = count + 1;
            } else{
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If anyone could explain how to make the app randomly select a quotew when the screen is touched, instead og going through them one by one, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What is your question? Be specific whats wrong with the code you have posted?

Comment: From a structure standpoint, I would consider making a `QuoteArrayList` class that extends `ArrayList`, with a constructor that takes a pair of strings and makes Quotes for you and adds to the list. Then implement a `getRandomQuote()` method that returns a random quote (using any of the solutions below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to generate a random number between 0 and however long your list is

```
Random rand = new Random()
int  n = rand.nextInt(quoteList.size() - 1);
```

Then use get the quote at that index

```
Quote random = quoteList.get(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Random random = new Random();    
int randomNum = random.nextInt(quoteList.size() - 1);
Quote randomQuote = quoteList.get(randomNum);
```

Comment: Don't subtract 1 - look at documentation for [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--).

Answer (score -1):

To randomly select a quote:

```
int randomNum = (int)(Math.random()*(quoteList.size() - 1));
Quote randomQuote = quoteList.get(randomNum);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String yourString = quoteList[new Random().nextInt(quoteList.length)];
```

Comment: You're getting a `String` from a list that contains `Quote`. Also, `ArrayList` uses `size()` not `length`, and to get an element from an ArrayList you need to use `.get(index)` not `[index]`,  and finally you are not subtracting 1 from the int you send to random, it returns the number of elements, not the last index.